# Symfony2 — render or redirect?

Tags: php, symfony

What is better? Returned redirect or to make render after successful submit form?

**Redirect:**

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        return $this->redirect(/* ... */);
    }

    return $this->render(/* ... */);
}
```

**Second:**

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        return $this->render(/* ... */);
    }

    return $this->render(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: `redirect()` so you can't resubmit the form by refreshing the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $this->render and $this->redirect Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442533/difference-between-this-render-and-this-redirect-symfony2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a form was sent via `POST` method - the best way is to redirect a user to the some page (for example, to the list of entities). It prevents resubmitting form by a user again.

> Better use `redirectToRoute()` method for Symfony `>=2.6`

But if you work with `GET` method - you definitely want to use `render()` method (for example, in order to display some filtering entities or data based on your GET-query).